# How long does a request take, when you're developing locally Magento?

Tags: php, macos, magento2, mamp

I have a general question, in order to look for ideas to make my programming time more efficient and productive.

I'm currently developing an e-commerce-platform on the bases of Magento 2.

I use a Mac (MacBook Pro of Mid 2015, 2.8 GHz, 16 GB, which was the highest possible equipment for that model), PhpStorm, MAMP (Pro), PHP 7.2 with Xdebug enabled (which I find necessary). On my Mac, of course, there are other processes running, but often I quit as many services as necessary, to get the most power of my computer. (for example all those cloud storage programs)

For Magento, dev-mode is enabled, the cache is on, I regularly have to clean it, of course. Also once in a while (for dependency injection) I clear the folder generated/code. After those actions, the requests usually take longer.

**My question consists of two parts:**

- A: How long does a usual request take for you? For me, It's sometimes 30 seconds to 1 minute or more. Sometimes the ajax-request double that time. The Problem about that is, that sometimes (especially on time-consuming requests), I get distracted and start doing something else. For example reading an article, watching a YouTube video or what so ever. Then this costs more time than the request itself. When I get back to work, I loose even more time.
  So for the sake of information and curiosity, I would like to know, how long takes it in your case?
- B: If it takes too long for you, what else are you doing in those times of a request? Do you have a productive way of spending that time? For example learning stuff...? But for which subject or learning action does it make sense to spend 30 seconds (that doesn't distract you too much)?

I know, it is not a pure programming question, but it is addressed to programmers. If there is another place to ask that question, please let me know.

Comment: on a lesser MBP, no mamp, no framework : average microservice , under 65 ms.  You may have a DNS resolver issue with these kinds of delays.  Also, measuring with xDebug , or worse an IDE listening on the xDebug connexion will render your measurements useless. Finally, your MBP will not be the production machine. Solve the 30 seconds (a real issue), develop with joy, deploy and measure.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg: What exactly do you mean with average microservice? For sure Magento is not a microservice. I know that the MBP is not the production machine. On the server, the same project (running in production mode and with an additional cache, js minified, and so on) is much faster. My intention is to make the development time more productive. So I can edit a file, run a request fast and see if it works almost immediately. On a symphony project, for instance, the request time with the same setup (MBP, MAMP, Xdebug) was much faster.